# Pass data to nunit testcase

Tags: c#, nunit

How pass data from the testrunner to the unittest?

For example an `output path` or `interface configuration` of the host machine?.

Comment: If you're doing that, you're probably not making a good unit test.  Unit tests should be pretty much self-contained.

Comment: We're not using `nunit` to test software on the host. We`re verifying a microcontroller plattform. Therefore we need for example the available interfaces on the computer to connect to the microcontroller.

Comment: Not much different to the way you'd run run integration test. e.g. run some db code against a database. Somewhere you have a config file with name, user, password etc. It's going to be painful probably, but it's not a unit test.

Comment: Yes you are right. But nunit is a powerful testcase runner. So we'd like to use it for our custom tests. Passing arbitrary data would we ver nice - for example the current `position` doing tests with a robot...

Answer (score 2):

You may have already gone done a different path at tis point but I though I would share this.  In post 2.5 versions of NUnit the ability to drive test cases in a via an external source was implemented.  I did a demo of a simple example using a CSV file.

The CSV was something that contained my two test inputs and the expected result.  So 1,1,2 for the first and so on.

**CODE**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using NUnit.Framework;
namespace NunitDemo
{
    public class AddTwoNumbers
    {
        private int _first;
        private int _second;

        public int AddTheNumbers(int first, int second)
        {
            _first = first;
            _second = second;

            return first + second;
        }
    }

    [TestFixture]
    public class AddTwoNumbersTest 
    {

        [Test, TestCaseSource("GetMyTestData")]
        public void AddTheNumbers_TestShell(int first, int second, int expectedOutput)
        {
            AddTwoNumbers addTwo = new AddTwoNumbers();
            int actualValue = addTwo.AddTheNumbers(first, second);

            Assert.AreEqual(expectedOutput, actualValue, 
                string.Format("AddTheNumbers_TestShell failed first: {0}, second {1}", first,second));
        }

        private IEnumerable<int[]> GetMyTestData()
        {
            using (var csv = new StreamReader("test-data.csv"))
            {
                string line;
                while ((line = csv.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    string[] values = line.Split(',');
                    int first = int.Parse(values[0]);
                    int second = int.Parse(values[1]);
                    int expectedOutput = int.Parse(values[2]);
                    yield return new[] { first, second, expectedOutput };
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then when you run it with the NUnit UI it looks like (I included a failure for example purposes:

[image]

Comment: Good example thanks. Can I suggest changing the TestCaseSource("GetMyTestData") to use nameof - TestCaseSource(nameof(GetMyTestData)), also the method needs to be static